# how to create a vertical menu with custom specific li order?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create a menu where the li should get to second menu when getting to a position like I want when li gets to 10 so then the rest goes to next side straight to it with css code as margin-left:100px and then when it get's again to 10 it should get to margin-left:200px and then the rest goes with this style..! like this way..

the important part is that I want it to be done all in one menu not in three menus for now I did it in three menus but I want it in one menu please..!

May be this image will help as :

http://www.huntedhunter.com/dropdown.png

Comment: Your code, examples, some viewable things to understand better the problem...

Comment: @lago Melanias : the question is updated please have a look again..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you basically can do is align from left to left. And let the elements break the line.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/h1ua00cd/1/

---

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something here...</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {margin: 0;padding:0;width: 660px;}
ul li {list-style:none;float: left;width:200px;margin-right: 20px;}
```

Comment: and what If i want to break the line and move to next link on a specific number as after 7 number li it should break the line so how that would be possible?

Comment: This container is dynamic, how much links you put, more lines the container occupies. For this case, what you basically can do is put more than one ul. DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/h1ua00cd/2/